# CSS grid layout doing nothing

Tags: html, css, browser

When this code is shown in Google Chrome the only formatting that is displayed is the colour. Each `<div>` simply stacks up on top of each other in the order that is set out in the html code.
[How it's shown in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLc8.jpg)

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

#title {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

#score {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: gray;
}

#stats {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: start;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

#board {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: green;
}

#controls {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="title">Game Title</div>
  <div id="score">Score</div>
  <div id="stats">Stats</div>
  <div id="board">Board</div>
  <div id="controls">Controls and more controls</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually your code is fine, but check if you did any CSS syntax error of if you have more CSS than this

Comment: The snippet you posted works. Try clearing the cache (CTRL + F5)?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply's I hadn't added a html or body element to my CSS. After adding these elements the formatting dropped in. Thanks again.